# How to add elements to the body of the Http request in android

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I want to construct a httprequest like below to access the rest webservice using post request. I have used spring for android API to generate the request. I am able to add header with httpHeader.add method but dont know add message to the body. The request format is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<headers>
<messagetype>1</messagetype>
<uniquekey>95C75718-C774-DF4E-0DB4-A7AEF55077AA</uniquekey>
</headers>
<authentication>
<clientname>xxx</clientname>
<servicename>login</servicename>
<username>xxx123</username>
<password>welcome123</password>
</authentication>
</root>
```

I dont how to add that  part. Please Help.

The code i done so far is below

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;


public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView webservice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Webservice);

        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        requestHeaders.add("messagetype", "1");
        requestHeaders.add("uniquekey", UniqueID.getUUID());
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://www.localhost:8080/restwebservice/login";
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        String result = responseEntity.getBody();       

        webservice.setText(result);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `Message` object and pass it to the RestTemplate. Check out section 2.6.5 of the [`RestTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html) documentation for specifics.

Note that the example there is different from your approach and uses `postForObject` instead of `exchange`. If you still want to stay with `exchange`, you should change the `HttpEntity` you are using for `requestEntity` and use one that allows you to add the body of your message to it. [`BasicHttpEntity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/BasicHttpEntity.html) should work just fine, although you will have to construct the XML in the body by hand. On the other hand, `postForObject` with the proper message formater will allow you to pass plain old Java object and get it properly serialized into XML automatically. There are many options for message formatters, but I would recommend Jackson as it is quite fast and well supported (even though it more known for its JSON support and less for XML).

Comment: Is there any way where i can create the xml request manually and pass the value as string or something?

Comment: Yes, you can use either `BasicHttpEntity`, and call `setContent` with an `InputStream` that has your XML, or you can use `StringHttpMessageConverter` and pass your XML as a regular `String` to the `postWithObject`. Note however, that if you go this route, the content type will be set to one of the `text/*`, and not to `application/xml`. This might or might not be a problem, depending on what framework you are using on the server side to parse the POSt request body.

Comment: Please give me the easiest sample code so that i can use that as a template to generate all the request.

Comment: Ok penov no problem the information you gave gives me something to think about. Thanks Mate.